# Let ImageView point to new ImageView object Android

Tags: android, imageview

I'm setting up an image cache and I have the following

```
    ImageView nimage = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imView1);

    ImageView value = imageCache.get(ei.imageURL);

    if (value != null) 
            nimage = value;   // this is the code I want to change
    else {

            new ImageLoadTask(ei.imageURL, nimage).execute();
            imageCache.put(ei.imageURL ,nimage);

    }
```

What do I replace the commented value with. I'm not sure why I can't let one imageView equal another imageView.

Comment: you are confusing image (possibly bitmaps) and imageview, which is a view that displays an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cache isn't caching the correct things.

You don't want to cache the ImageView itself- an instance of a View is tied to the Context in which it was created, and thus is typically not a great object to cache.

What it sounds like you actually want to cache is the image (the Bitmap object) that you download from the URL that you are providing to your `ImageLoadTask`. If you cache this, then you can simply call `nimage.setImageBitmap()` to use your cached bitmap instead of downloading it.

Comment: Brilliant! Worked a charm. I was doing it totally wrong.